# Add folder to environment variable

Tags: macos, zend-framework, osx-lion, environment-variables

At the moment I'm trying to install the Zend Framework. The Framework comes with a command line tool, `zf.sh` for *nix systems and `zf.bat` for Windows systems. To use the `zf.sh`, I tried to add it to my environment path. Somehow I can't get it to work.

My `~/.profile`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/

export ZEND=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/zf.sh

# 2012-06-05 make alias for zf
# Make an alias for the zf.sh so we can call it with zf instead of zf.sh
alias zf=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/zf.sh

# Add the path to the Zend files so that the zf.sh can work with them
ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/Zend
```

My `/etc/paths`

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
~/Development/play-2.0
/Applications/Racket\ v5.2/bin/
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/
```

But when I do `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/X11R6/bin
```

Or `zf`

```
fish: Unknown command 'zf'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `alias zf='/var/www/zf1_trunk/bin/zf.sh'` to `.bash_profile` should let you access the zf command line

```
at ~/.bash_profile
alias zf='/var/www/zf1_trunk/bin/zf.sh'
```

Comment: But I have to change the line to my location of the zf.sh right? So in my case, in `.bash_profile`, `alias zf='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/zf.sh'`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MAMP in MAC OS X

1. Open Terminal
2. in terminal type "vi .bash_profile"
3. enter the line in editor

alias zf='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/zf.sh'

change location acc. to your software installation

1. Exit Terminal
2. Open terminal and then type zf

Answer (score 0):

Typically, bash on OSX uses .bash_profile, not .profile... See if it's sourcing it correctly.

Comment: I changed the filename form `.profile` to `.bash_profile`, but it still doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Where are spaces that should not be?

Comment: Your PATH should be of the form: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ... else, it'll only look for binaries in /usr/bin :-)